# RPUD : cannot find a dll that exists

Tags: r, gpu, rstudio

I am trying to use my GPU (GeForce GTX 770, CC 3.0) in R. I am using R 3.1.2. I have successfully installed CUDA that I use in non R projects. Now, I just installed `rpud` and `rpudplus` from the .zip file in my R environment.

```
install.packages("C:/Users/Windows/Desktop/R/rpux_0.5.0/rpud_0.5.0.zip", 
                 repos = NULL)
package ‘rpud’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

And when I try to use it :

```
require(rpud)
Loading required package: rpud
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/rpud/libs/x64/rpud.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  Cannot find file (Le module spécifié est introuvable.)
```

However, the .dll is in the specified path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "cannot find file" is incomplete. It actually means that "cannot find all dependency lib of the file". In this case, it most likely means that the expected CUDA version is not found.

For rpud v0.5.0, it MUST have CUDA 6.5 installed in the system. For rpud v0.5.1, it MUST have CUDA 7.0 instead.